# TinyMCE not showing image upload button

Tags: php, upload, tinymce

I'm new with TinyMCE and it'is my first time to use it with image upload.
Just as editor it works perfectly but i can upload images.. **because the upload button doesn't appear**
I added image as setup option in plugins and in toolbar, i also tried many-many different setups / configs and read the manual but can't figure out what the problem is..

```
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#content',
    plugins: 'anchor autolink charmap codesample emoticons image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table | align lineheight | numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat',
    images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
    file_picker_callback: (callback, value, meta) => {
    // Provide file and text for the link dialog
    if (meta.filetype == 'file') {
      callback('mypage.html', { text: 'My text' });
    }

    // Provide image and alt text for the image dialog
    if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
      callback('myimage.jpg', { alt: 'My alt text' });
    }

    // Provide alternative source and posted for the media dialog
    if (meta.filetype == 'media') {
      callback('movie.mp4', { source2: 'alt.ogg', poster: 'image.jpg' });
    }
  }
  });
  
  tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages(function(success) {
    $.post('ajax/post.php', tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()).done(function() {
      console.log("Uploaded images and posted content as an ajax request.");
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is how is see the "Insert image" dialog..

[image]

And this is how it should be:

[image]

What i have to change in order to be able to upload the images..?

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.